# How to get Magento cache refreshed by key?

Tags: php, magento

I would like to refresh my extension cache when Magento 
Collections Data    Collection data files.  COLLECTION_DATA cache is refreshed and also for other events, which cleans this cache.

I have a custom class, the main parts are:

```
$this->_usecache = Mage::app()->useCache('collections');
if ($this->_usecache){
    $cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
    $key = "mycategory".$this->_config['rootid'];
    $this->tmpAllItems = $cache->load($key);
} else {
    $this->tmpAllItems = false;
}
if ($this->tmpAllItems === false){
    $this->tmpAllItems = array();
    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $categories = $model->getCategories($this->_config['rootid'], 0, true, false, true);
    $k = array_keys($categories->getNodes());
    $parent = $categories[$k[0]]->getParent();
    $this -> treeToFlat($parent);
    if ($this->_usecache) 
    {
         $cache->save(serialize($this->tmpAllItems),
                      $key,
                      array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG,
                            Mage_Core_Model_App::CACHE_TAG)
                     );
    } else {
        $this->tmpAllItems = unserialize($this->tmpAllItems);
    }
    return $this->tmpAllItems;
```

So, my target is to refresh/clean this cache too when Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG is cleaned. How is this possible?

### UPDATE #1

When I have used

```
$cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();
```

instead of

```
$cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
```

The clean started to work. When I have a category, the list refreshed, but if nothing happened, it stayed cache. Also could someone explain why is this possible with this changing?

### Solution

```
...
$cache->save(serialize($this->tmpAllItems),$key,array('my_cache_tag'));
....
```

Then clear:

> ```
>     $cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
>     foreach($cache->getTags() as $tag){
>         if(strpos($tag, 'my_cache_tag')){
>             $ids = $cache->getIdsMatchingAnyTags(array($tag));
>             foreach($ids as $id){
>                 $cache->remove($id);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found a solution for this problem, i use observer when click refresh cache in admin panel
you can see details at [my blog](http://www.worldofcoder.com/2013/11/create-new-cache-type-in-magento.html)

step1: create observer with event when click refresh in admin panel:

```
    <events>
   <adminhtml_cache_refresh_type>
    <observers>
     <yournamespace_yourextenstion_model_observer>
      <type>singleton</type>
      <class>YourNameSpace_YourExtenstion_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>adminhtml_cache_refresh_type</method>
     </yournamespace_yourextenstion_model_observer>
    </observers>
   </adminhtml_cache_refresh_type>
  </events
```

now, we can create file name as: Observer.php follow this path: YourNameSpace/YourExtenstion/Model/Observer.php and add this code in to Observer.php

this is content for observer.php file

```
class YourNameSpace_YourExtenstion_Model_Observer
{
 public function adminhtml_cache_refresh_type($observer)
 {
  $request = Mage::app()--->getRequest()->getPost('types');
  if(in_array('ee_content', $request))
  {
   $cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
   $tags = $cache->getTags();
   $ee_content = '';
   foreach($tags as $tag)
   {
    if(strpos($tag, 'ee_content'))
    {
     $ee_content = $tag;
    }
   }
   if($ee_content !='')
   {


    $ids = $cache->getIdsMatchingAnyTags(array($ee_content));
    foreach($ids as $id)
    {
     $cache->remove($id);
    }
   }

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Link only answers are typically not acceptable on Stack Overflow, as the answer could be rendered useless should the link ever become dead. You should post the actual solution here instead.

Comment: Please post the relevant content from your blog into the answer here

Answer (score 2):

check event **application_clean_cache**

when clear cache like - `Mage::app()->cleanCache();`

or when system saves product etc...

and take a look on event - **adminhtml_cache_refresh_type**
when clearing cache via admin panel

and your code in observer

```
Mage::app()->getCache()->clean('all', array('my_tag'));
```

and need add some logic to Observer,
for check need refresh cache or not

Answer (score 0):

`getCacheInstance()` will get you core cache model instance, while `getCache()` will get for you cache object.

To clean everything, by `getCacheInstance()` and `getCache()`, you need to use it like below:

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
Mage::app()->getCache()->clean();
```

To clean your custom cache type, you will use:

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('your_custom_cache_type');
```

Comment: I think we have some misunderstanding. I don't want to clear the cache manually or by PHP. I want that Magento clear my cache automatically, when an admin add/modify/etc categories or when the cache catalog cache refreshed in the backend options of Magento. Am I clear?

Comment: you need to check for an event that will be fired.Place an observer and as stated above Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('your_custom_cache_type'); in that observer will do what you want to achieve.

Comment: But what is the event name what I should observer? For example for COLLECTION_DATA cache refresh event?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can create your own dispatch event by using Mage::dispatchEvent method. Override your Model file Mage_Catalog_Model_Category and register a new dispatcher over there.